# Why are there two different notations for negation in boolean logic?

Tags: notation, math-history, boolean-algebra

For the boolean variable $x$, there are two notations for its negation: $\neg x$ and $\bar x$. So why are there two different notations?

Comment: I've never seen $\overline x$. I've seen $\lnot A$ for the complement of a set, but notation for sets is different in general.

Comment: There are more than two notations: $\lnot x$, $\bar{x}, x', 1-x$, $!x$, $\sim x$ (the latter two are common in programming)

Comment: But notation is just a choice, and, as Weaam notes, there is a lot of different notations for "not."

Comment: $\overline x$ is painful for typesetting ($\overline{(x\land y)\lor z}$ just looks awful and is, in old-style typesetting, very hard to do.) It is tricky even if only used with single letters, but it is particularly bad for longer phrases. Also, logicians want to deal with text as sequential strings for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The "reason" is purely historial: the use of symbols changes during time.

The "overline" symbol for *negation* it seems is due to [C.S.Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-logic/).

See e.g.:

- Charles Sanders Peirce, [On the Algebra of Logic](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-2369442/2369442#page/n3/mode/2up) (1880), page 18:

> This we shall write $P_1 \overline < C_1$, *a dash over any symbol signifying in our notationt the negative of that symbol*.

and:

- Charles Sanders Peirce (editor), [Studies in Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GRlCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18) (1883): *ON THE ALGEBRA OF LOGIC*, by [Christine Ladd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Ladd-Franklin), page 18:

> The negative of a term or a proposition or a symbol is indicated by a line drawn over it. $\overline a =$ what is not $a$.

---

The sign was used in mathematical logic also by:

- David Hilbert & [Wilhelm Ackermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Ackermann), [Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&pg=PA3) (1928); see Engl.transl.(1950) of the 2nd German ed.,1937, page 3:

> 1. $\overline X$ (read "*not* $X$") stands for the opposite or contradictory 
>      of $X$, that is, for that sentence which is true if $X$ is false and which is false if $X$ is true.

---

The symbol $\lnot$ for *negation* is quite recent; according to the site [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) [but see also the references to Peano and Russell for the use of $\sim$]:

> it was first used in 1930 by [Arend Heyting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arend_Heyting) in “Die formalen Regeln der intuitionistischen Logik,” *Sitzungsberichte der preußischen Akademie der Wissenschaften, phys.-math. Klasse*, 1930, p. 42-65.

Compare with:

- Arend Heyting, [Intuitionism: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=qfp_-Fo9yWMC&pg=PA102) (1956, 3rd ed., 1971), page 102:

> The negation $\lnot$ is the strong mathematical negation which we 
>   have already discussed. [...] Then $\lnot p$ can be asserted if and only if we possess a construction which from the supposition that a construction $p$ 
>   were carried out, leads to a contradiction.